# When are InnoDB table index statistics updated?

Tags: mysql, innodb

In a vanilla build of MySQL 5.5.20, when are InnoDB table index statistics updated?  What events trigger such updates?  I've seen comments suggesting that the following might trigger it:

- table is opened for first time
- query is run against table
- ANALYZE TABLE
- size of table changes by some threshold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look for this variable

```
mysql> show variables like '%metadata%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_stats_on_metadata | ON    |
+--------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

According to the MySQL Docs, when [innodb_stats_on_metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_stats_on_metadata) is set (by default), InnoDB updates statistics during metadata statements such as SHOW TABLE STATUS or SHOW INDEX, or when accessing the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables TABLES or STATISTICS. (These updates are similar to what happens for ANALYZE TABLE.) When disabled, InnoDB does not update statistics during these operations. Disabling this variable can improve access speed for schemas that have a large number of tables or indexes. It can also improve the stability of execution plans for queries that involve InnoDB tables.

Once disabled, [you would have to run `ANALYZE TABLE` on the InnoDB tables of your choice. Make sure you have SELECT and INSERT privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html).

Comment: Thanks.  If It turn it off, when *will* index statistics be updated?

Comment: You have to do ANALYZE TABLE then

Comment: I found a Percona reference --http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/10/06/when-does-innodb-update-table-statistics-and-when-it-can-bite/ -- that suggests the statistics are updated when the table size changes by 1/16, but I can't find any corroboration for that statement.  Do you know if that's true or not?

Comment: From that link, it says : "2.When 1 / 16th of the table or 2Billion rows has been modified, whichever comes first. ./row/row0mysql.c:row_update_statistics_if_needed". You may have to download the source code and go find the file row0mysql.c and look around. That is the deepest corrobrative evidence there is.

Comment: I checked row0mysql.c for 5.5.20.  It defines a function `row_update_statistics_if_needed` that behaves as described: it calls another method `dict_update_statistics` if the table-update counter is over 2 billion, or if the table-update counter is greater than 1/16 of the number of rows in the table.  This `row_update_statistics_if_needed` method is called on insert, update, and cascade-update.

Comment: @All: Also see changes in 5.6.2 http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/04/innodb-persistent-statistics-at-last

Comment: @gbn nice link about 5.6.2. You should submitted it as an answer for the future